# Running a function in apps script when a certain value in a range is changed to a specific Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have this function that I use to loop thru a spreadsheet and send emails depending on the value of the status Column. I'm currently using a trigger that runs the sendEmailFunction on change in the spreadsheet.

However, I would prefer to write a programmatic trigger, that runs this sendEmailFunction when the cell value in the statusCol Range is changed from blank -> Initiate. I have tried using the onEdit(e) method, but can't seem to get it to work. Thanks

```
function sendEmailFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var totalRows = ss.getLastRow() -1;
  var statusCol = ss.getRange(2, 16, totalRows, 1).getValues(); 

  for (var i=0; i<statusCol.length; i++)
  {
    if(statusCol[i] == 'Email Sent' || statusCol[i] == null)
    {
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      var col1 = ws.getRange(i+2, 1).getValue(); 
      var col2 = ws.getRange(i+2, 2).getValue(); 
      var status = ws.getRange(i+2, 16).getValue();
    }
  }

  if (status == 'Initiate'){
    MailApp.sendEmail('emailaddress@live.com', 'subject', 'body')
  }

}
```

Comment: onEdit only works for user edits not for changes due to other scripts or formulas

Comment: I'd change the function name and try to set an installable trigger for it on edit basis. If the edited cell is changed and its value is x, then shoot the msg.

Comment: @santosOnit how does that accomplish anything different.  The OP is trying to generate an onEdit trigger by editing the cell with another script?  Whether it's installable or otherwise it does not work.

Comment: Is the value changed from blank to Initiate manually?

Comment: @santosOnit yes the value is changed manually

Comment: Thus, my suggestion above. Make sure you get active cell and its "address" as the criteria for firing the email sending